# Servlet context URLs

Tags: java, servlets, jboss5.x

I deployed a war named `test` in the JBoss AS.

When i go to browser and type the url `http://localhost:8080/test`, i get the `login.jsp` page, which is the welcome page.

When i hit the submit button a servlet gets invoked name `CheckLoginServlet` (`onSubmit` i have redirected to `/test/servlet/CheckLoginServlet`). On successful login this servlet redirects to a jsp (`MFrame.jsp`) which is inside the `docroot/main/jsp`. The url looks like this `http://localhost:8080/main/jsp/MFrame.jsp?sid=13045798560`, and i get a 404 error.

The reason is that the url is not including the context `test`, now when i explicitly modify the url in the browser to include test in it (now the url looks like `http://localhost:8080/test/main/jsp/MFrame.jsp?sid=13045798560`), the page successfully renders.

My question is why the context `test` is not coming in the url, as it is the context root.

Comment: How are you doing to redirect to `MFrame.jsp`?  What does your code look like?

Answer (score 3):

Redirects are web-server relatives. So If you have `.sendRedirect("/main/jsp/MFrame.jsp")`, the context path will be omitted. That's because redirects are an HTTP notion and they happen in the browser (they are called client-side redirects)

You have a couple of options:

- use forward - `req.getRequestDispatcher("/main/jsp/MFrame.jsp").forward(req, res);` - this will trigger a server-side redirect, and it is context-relative
- append the context to the redirect url (`request.getContextPath()`)
- use relative paths in the redirect

Comment: `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/errors/401.html");`